# How to remove highlighting from emails in Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, color

I created a rule that applies a mint green color to a lot of emails in my mailbox. I no longer want that color on those emails and I do not see a way to remove this highlighting for even a single email. I know I could create a new rule to give them a different color, but there is no rule semantics for removing color either.

It seems that all of my email's subjects in Mac Mailbox are now permanently stained.

Comment: Right click remove styles I HAVE TO POST 30 CHAR IGNORE THIS LINE!

Comment: @mandoza3 I don't see any "Remove styles" item in the contextual menu... I have Mail.app 9.3.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can do it by adding a new Rule [I haven't tested it, because I don't want to actually reset my own colours…]

Try setting Any condition > Every Message > Set Colour…

[image]

Note: the 'Other colour seems to depend on your current Colour choice in the Colours floater - Format > Show Colours…

[image]

You can do it manually, select one message, pick a colour - but it seems very hit & miss, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a colors button to your toolbar. Right-click the top toolbar, click customize, then drag the colors button to your toolbar. Then you can select the messages and change the color.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that rebuilding your mailbox will get rid of all coloring. However, this process will cause **Mail** to re-download all emails in that mailbox, which depending on the size of the mailbox may take a very long time and use up a lot of bandwidth.

If you’re on a metered connection, that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I discovered a good solution to this without 3rd party apps, scripts, work-arounds.

Since google brought me to a different question for this, my full write-up is there: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461044/498532

I wanted to make sure to reply here to avoid the annoying situation when google results show a page where the question is just marked as "duplicate" by the community and nobody posts a link to the duplicate or a solution.

I figured out a way to do this without using special apps/scripts, complicated work-arounds or hacks; **this solution will actually "put it back to the way it was."** It was just a matter of figuring out the right colors to choose that will maintain UI consistency when switching themes.

To set message text and background to restore the default "non-colors", you want to use the Color Palette selector, and choose "Developer" in the dropdown. You'll see a list with colors named for their UI purpose.

The color to choose to restore original Text color is:

***disabledControlTextColor***

The color to choose to restore original Text Background is:

***alternatingContentBackgroundColor***

Again, these are theme compatible and will change appropriately with the OS theme setting.

Comment: Thanks for contributing!  Your answer might benefit with an [edit] focusing on the solution, ideally at the beginning and (much) less emphasis on the background narrative.  A straight to the point answer works much better in this Q/A format.